# How to avoid first letter to be capitalized on input field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, antd

I'm working on a react web application mostly used from mobile.
We got an input field and we would like to AVOID the first letter to be capitalized.

The field can contain capitalized letter, but the first one should be lowercase for sure.

E.G.

> [www.mylink.com/R44iaYYIla](http://www.mylink.com/R44iaYYIla)

what it's currently happening is that we get the following:

> Www.mylink.com/R44iaYYIla

It's not about what we store, we don't have problem on manipulating the string. It's about the UX, so that when the user writes www it doesn't start with a capital W

here's the component

```
import React from "react";
import { Form } from "antd";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function MyForm() {

const [form] = Form.useForm();

return (
    <>
        <Form form={form} name="my-form">
            <Form.Item name="my-field" rules={rules.url} validateFirst={true}>
                <TextField
                    label="my-field-label"
                    autoFocus
                    type="text"
                />
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    </>
);
```

}

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material UI TextField has an `autoCapitalize` field to handle this.

Try:

```
import React from "react";
import { Form } from "antd";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function MyForm() {

const [form] = Form.useForm();

return (
    <>
        <Form form={form} name="my-form">
            <Form.Item name="my-field" rules={rules.url} validateFirst={true}>
                <TextField
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    label="my-field-label"
                    autoFocus
                    type="text"
                />
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    </>
);
```

Comment: I found an issue whit this approach, it also affects copied link. I.E. 
copying Www.AWEsomething.com will paste Www.awesomething.com

Comment: @Koop4 probably need to do some text transformation at that point by transforming the characters onChange

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<TextField
  inputProps={{ style: { textTransform: 'none' } }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answers above, but what worked for me was to pass an object in inputProps without nesting a "style" object. Like this:

<TextField
inputProps={{ autoCapitalize: 'none' }}
/>

For reference, see this closed [github issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/10278).